# python mysql is this a parameterized statement? choking on special characters

Tags: python, mysql

While trying to understand how to get everything that someone could
type (into my gui), into my database, my searches led to a lot of info-
like;

"Don't do this or that - do ALWAYS use prepared statements instead"

Which led to; "Mysql uses wannabe prepared statements, called parameterized statements"

So I searched that, but the examples seem to be what I already am doing, namely the %s stuff.

I found one recommendation that seemed to be using curly braces with regular .format
string formatting directly in the mysql execute. <-is this good?

I found a recommendation (it was argued AGAINST by many) to use re.sub. <-i suspect not, but i put most stock in answers from SO

I found a recommendation to use "'%s'" instead of '%s' <-tried this, it did allow quotes, but not backslash

What else is needed to allow the insert of any of the type-able characters. 
Backslash and quotes are what I know about but I need to cover all like @#$!~%+(&^.

Is there more to a parameterized statement that basically means "handle it yourself with your application code" depending on your needs? I would be grateful even for a strong hint, I just been reading around in circles for 18 hours. I need some direction.

```
cursor.execute ("""
        INSERT INTO dailylog 
        (emp, content, entrytime, shift, shiftday, containingweek)
        VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
        """ % (emp, content1, entrytime, shift, shiftday, containingweek,));

cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: It is not parameterized. You're using the string formatting operator `%` to format a string.

Comment: no need for quotes around the '%s' in the string, no need for semicolon at the end.

Comment: see http://bobby-tables.com/python.html

Comment: Thanks Pykler. I tried  making the way the bobby-tables site showed work with my insert (his example was a select, I think) but after a few hours Ricardos answer came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute the `%` (the one before `(emp`) with a `,`. That's the way it works. Otherwise, you're asking Python to do normal string rendering.

Also, remove the single quotes around the `'`. It's MySQL's escaping code the one that should put them if needed.

So, to be specific, your code should look like this:

```
cursor.execute ("""
        INSERT INTO dailylog 
        (emp, content, entrytime, shift, shiftday, containingweek)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """, (emp, content1, entrytime, shift, shiftday, containingweek))
```

PS: Note that I removed the `,` after `containingweek`. You need the extra comma in one-element tuples, for syntactic reasons, but this tuple contains more than one element...

Comment: To be sure I understand, is this now parameterized? I hope so. But what about putting the command into a command string and executing that like I was researching after reading the http://bobby-tables.com/python.html site? Is that part not a important part of doing this right? Thanks you very much, anything they could type in seems to make it through now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is. Note that you're passing two arguments to the function: the parametrized query, and then the arguments to substitute those parameters with. **VERY** important is that I've removed the single quotes around the parameters. You must let the library substitute that itself.

Comment: The problem with your initial approach is that you're asking Python to do a normal "string rendering" (substitute values into the string), and Python doesn't know anything about SQL, so it doesn't know when it is right to expand `'` to `''`, and things like that. Using that approach leaves your query open to attacks.